# How do I disable Bitlocker Encryption settings using Microsoft Intune?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, intune

We've activated Intune BitLocker encryption and configured it needs a password to unlock.

Since we don't want our users to change the BitLocker pin, we want to disable the Settings below.
All users have Admin privileges.

[image]

For all non Germans, it's under:

```
Control Panel\System and Security\BitLocker Drive Encryption
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the local policy group editor I was able to disable this page.

Press Win + R and enter "gpedit.msc" then hit Enter.

Under User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel

There is the setting "Hide specific Control Panel items".
You enable it and have to add the settings to hide.

Here is a List of settings:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/control-panel/index

You have to use the Canonical name

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[How to Enable or Disable Standard Users from Changing BitLocker PIN or Password in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96939-enable-disable-standard-users-changing-bitlocker-pin-password.html)
for details. Below is a summary of two methods:

**Group Policy Editor**

The policy is "Disallow standard users from changing the PIN or password",
found in:
`Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Operating System Drives`

**Registry**

Use the following `.reg` file to disable
standard users from changing BitLocker PIN or Password:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"DisallowStandardUserPINReset"=dword:00000001
```

To enable use:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"DisallowStandardUserPINReset"-
```